# Quick sort CLRS Partition Always on n/3 Element

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, recurrence

I am wondering if this is the correct recurrence when assuming that the pivot is always at the n/3 position when using Quicksort from CLRS.

The recurrence I have is below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the pivot always happens to be at the n/3 position then the recurrence for T(n) is:

[image: recurrence]

I'll explain where each of the three components of the sum comes from:

- [image: cn]

  You need linear time to iterate over all the elements of the array, deciding for each element at which side of the pivot it belongs.
- [image: one third]

  After positioning all the elements to the left or to the right of the pivot, you recursively sort the left side of the array which consists of about (n-1)/3 elements. This number comes from the fact that the pivot is at the n/3 position.
- [image: two thirds]

  Recursively sort the right side of the array which consists of about 2(n-1)/3 elements.

You haven't asked about solving the recurrence but I'll note that it solves to nlog(n) just as in the case in which the pivot always happens to be at the the n/2 position.

Comment: Would a more exact analysis be T(n) = T((n-3)/3) + T(2n/3) + cn?

Comment: For example, take n to be 12. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]. There are 3 elements on the left side and 8 elements on the right side.

Comment: In order to make it slightly more exact you can replace the T((n-1)/3) with T(floor(n/3)-1) and also replace T(2(n-1)/3) with T(n-floor(n/3)). Also replace the cn with n. The slightly modified recurrence counts the number of comparisons made by quicksort assuming the pivot always happens to be at the floor(n/3) position. In the case of n=12, the chosen pivot is positioned at 4. So by substituting n with 12 we get: T(12)=12+T(12/3-1)+T(12-12/3) or T(12)=12+T(3)+T(8).